# Word that means allure of the underworld

Tags: single-word-requests

I came across a word a while back and am not able to recall it at all though I found that word most useful to know.

It roughly means the allure or attractiveness of the underworld, in particular the gambling, sex, drugs, etc.

The word can be sort of like this.

> The _____ of London in the 1960s under the Kray brothers motivated many gangsters to travel there.

Comment: It's an awkward sentence for a drop-in word, but *atmosphere of intrigue* and *sordid milieu* could work with some rearranging. "The sordid milieu of the Kray brothers' London motivated many gangsters to travel there in the 1960s."

Answer (score 3):

- The **seductiveness** of London in the 1960s under the Kray brothers motivated many gangsters to travel there.

> *Seductive* is an adjective that describes the fascinating magnetic pull that someone or something has, an attractive quality that tempts
> you in some way....

[[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/seductive#:%7E:text=Seductive%20is%20an%20adjective%20that,tempts%20you%20in%20some%20way.&text=The%20word%20comes%20from%20the,that%20is%20a%20seductive%20person.)]

Answer (score -1):

1. The **epicurean** lifestyle of London in the 1960s under the Kray brothers motivated many gangsters to travel there.

> Epicurean: fond of or adapted to luxury or indulgence in sensual pleasures; having luxurious tastes or habits, especially in eating and drinking.

2. The **voluptuousness** of London in the 1960s under the Kray brothers motivated many gangsters to travel there.

> Voluptuous: Given to or spent in enjoyment of luxury, pleasure, or sensual gratifications

Comment: -1: there's a huge gulf between "allure of the underworld" and words that simply refer to indulgence of the senses.